# List only prints last element

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and appreciate all the help i can get. Programs works, but I have this problem where I want to print all countries (3 countries) in a list but I only get the last country as output.

How do I print all the countries in a list?

Main window:

```
        public void euHourly()
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> euHourly = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        euHourly.Add(Tuple.Create("Riga", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=57&lon=23&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=e4ef2ac494977d735811075476bcc0bf"));
        euHourly.Add(Tuple.Create("Tallinn", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=59.43&lon=24.75&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=e4ef2ac494977d735811075476bcc0bf"));
        euHourly.Add(Tuple.Create("Moscow", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lon=37.61&lat=55.75&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=e4ef2ac494977d735811075476bcc0bf"));

        foreach (var link in euHourly)
        {
            var filepath = Orai.Default.txtBox + "\\Europe.txt";
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath);
            sw.Close();
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite), Encoding.UTF8);

            try
            {
                List<Tuple<string, string>> url = getData.euDataDaily(link.Item2);
                file.WriteLine("City;Temperature;Icon");
                foreach (var tuple in url)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(link.Item1 + ";" + tuple.Item1 + ";" + tuple.Item2) ;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No data");
                    }
                }
                file.Close();
                pbStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pbStatus.Value = pbStatus.Value + 5, DispatcherPriority.Background);

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data");
            }
        }
    }
```

getData window:

```
    public static List<Tuple<string, string>> euDataDaily(string url)
    {
        var aTuple = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { };
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString(url);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        string conditionCode="";
        string unixDate = "";
        string dayTemp="";

        foreach (var result in o["daily"])
            {
                unixDate = (string)result["dt"];

            if (unixDate.Equals("1617786000"))
                {
                    dayTemp = (string)result["temp"]["day"];
                }
   
                if (unixDate.Equals("1617786000"))
                {
                    foreach (var resultas in result["weather"])
                    {
                        conditionCode = (string)resultas["description"];
                    }      
                }             
            }

            aTuple.Add(Tuple.Create(dayTemp, conditionCode));
        
        return aTuple;
    }
```

Europe.txt

```
City;Temperature;Icon
Moscow;9.32;light rain
```

Also I'm new to this website. If anything is inappropriate with my question, let me know. Thanks for all help :).

Answer (score 0):

You create the file 3 times. You need to move `File.CreateText` and related code (e.g. the file header) outside of the `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I move out that code, then my program shows "No data".

Comment: Did you move  `.Close`? You should only close once.

Comment: Btw. If you change `catch` to `catch (Exception ex)` you can see what the problem is.